# Поставить DISLIKE, удаляя LIKE. Django

Tags: python, django

Возможно кто-нибудь сможет помочь.
Имеется проект на  Django, в который я пытаюсь добавить функцию LIKE/DISLIKE.
Как пользователю добавить или снять LIKE/DISLIKE я разобрался. Но моя логика имеет пробел, в том что пользователь может поставить и LIKE и DISLIKE (это не совсем правильно). Поэтому я хочу сделать "финт ушами" следующим образом: если пользователь поставил LIKE, потом передумал и ставит DISLIKE, то что бы DISLIKE приплюсовался, а LIKE отминусовался автоматически (так же как происходит на YouTube).

У меня есть следующие вьюхи:

1. class AddLikeView(View)
2. class RemoveLikeView(View)
3. class AddDisLikeView(View)
4. class RemoveDisLikeView(View)

Я так понимаю, мне надо прописать какую то логику в AddDisLikeView и RemoveLikeView. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
class AddDisLikeView(View):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    blog_post_id = int(request.POST.get('blog_post_id'))
    user_id = int(request.POST.get('user_id'))
    url_from = request.POST.get('url_from')

    user_inst = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    blog_post_inst = News.objects.get(id=blog_post_id)

    try:
        blog_dislike_inst = BlogDisLikes.objects.get(blog_post=blog_post_inst, liked_by=user_inst)
    except Exception as e:
        blog_dislike = BlogDisLikes(blog_post=blog_post_inst,
                              disliked_by=user_inst,
                              dislike=True)
        blog_dislike.save()
    return redirect(url_from)


class RemoveLikeView(View):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    blog_likes_id = int(request.POST.get('blog_likes_id'))
    url_from = request.POST.get('url_from')

    blog_like = BlogLikes.objects.get(id=blog_likes_id)
    blog_like.delete()
    return redirect(url_from)
```

Comment: Я все понимаю, но почему бы не использовать одно поле типа int, -1 0 +1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынеси функционал по увеличению, уменьшению лайков и дизлайков в сервисные методы и вызывай их из своих view

например:

```
def add_dislike(post, user):
    try:
        BlogDisLikes.objects.get(blog_post=post, liked_by=user)
    except BlogDisLikes.DoesNotExist:
        BlogDisLikes.objects.create(blog_post=post, liked_by=user)

        
def remove_dislike(post, user):
    BlogDisLikes.objects.filter(blog_post=post, liked_by=user).delete()
    
    
def add_like(post, user):
    try:
        BlogLikes.objects.get(blog_post=post, liked_by=user)
    except BlogLikes.DoesNotExist:
        BlogLikes.objects.create(blog_post=post, liked_by=user)

        
def remove_like(post, user):
    BlogLikes.objects.filter(blog_post=post, liked_by=user).delete()
```

и тогда твои view будут выглядеть как-то так

```
class AddDisLikeView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        blog_post_id = int(request.POST.get('blog_post_id'))
        user_id = int(request.POST.get('user_id'))
        url_from = request.POST.get('url_from')

        user_inst = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        blog_post_inst = News.objects.get(id=blog_post_id)
        remove_like(post=blog_post_inst, user=user_inst)
        add_dislike(post=blog_post_inst, user=user_inst)
        return redirect(url_from)
```

если ты сделаешь у модели `BlogDisLikes` уникальный ключ `blog_post`, `liked_by`
тогда можно просто пытаться сразу создать дизлайк, отлавливая исключение

```
from django.db import IntegrityError


def add_dislike(post, user):
    try:
        BlogDisLikes.objects.create(blog_post=post, liked_by=user)
    except IntegrityError:
        pass  # ничего не делаем, если такой диздайк уже есть
```

аналогично и для модели лайков

Comment: Я понял Вашу логику. Спасибо. Но вот стала вылезать ошибка : 'Manager' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: у меня была ошибка при удалении, теперь исправил. По поводу удаления объектов https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Comment: Да, удаление заработало, но тут же выскочила новая проблема: type object 'BlogDisLikes' has no attribute 'DoesNotExists'.  Читаю на форумах про эту ошибку, но не могу понять как исправить её применительно в моём случае

Comment: s в конце лишняя - DoesNotExist. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist

Comment: Андрей, было ещё несколько нюансов, но я их сам уже исправил. Спасибо Вам большое, что навели на путь истины))